# Quantum Theory without explicit measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

I've been reading around a lot about measurement in Quantum Theory. Asher Peres's *Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods* in particular has been of great help, since most books I've read tend to gloss over measurement. Peres essentially calls QT a recipe to predict the results of measurements given certain preparetions, that is the result of experiments on quantum systems.

This got me thinking, how do you apply QT to situations where no explicit measurementi is being made? Peres has this to say:

> More generally, we may relate a quantum state to a set of equivalent experimental procedures—provided that it is in principle possible to verify that these
> procedures are indeed equivalent. For instance, we may use quarter wave plates
> supplied by different manufacturers, or we may devise an altogether different
> method to analyze circular polarization. Occasionally, we may even renounce
> the use of any equipment, and consider purely mental experiments, as long as
> we are sure that a real experiment is possible in principle. For example, it is
> perfectly legitimate to consider the state of an electron located at the center of
> the Sun. A measurement of a spin component of that electron is undoubtedly
> very difficult, and it is ruled out for sure by budgetary constraints; but it is
> not ruled out by the laws of physics—as they are known today. Therefore it
> is legitimate to use quantum mechanics to compute the physical properties of
> a stellar plasma, just as it is used to discuss metallic conduction, or helium
> superfluidity, that we observe in our laboratory.

But he doesn't go into much more detail. My question is, with no discussion on interpretation, in the purest 'shut up and calculate' sense, if I wanted to apply QT to a system that's not being exlicitly measured, say, atoms in a gas, electrons in a conductor, or photons in the Sun, how would I go about doing it?

I'd also really appreciate reading sources on this, particularly textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's two questions lurking in your question.

First, in what situations can we apply the formalism of quantum mechanics, when there is no measurement? The answer is that (as far as we know) you can apply quantum mechanics to *any* physical system (except those involving strong gravitational fields). It may not be practical, but in principle quantum mechanics always applies. Since I have excluded measurement from this part of the question, what I mean is that you start from some state of interest, write down the Hamiltonian for your system, and evolve the state to any earlier or later time using the unitary time evolution operator. Of course that one sentence description belies what can easily be months or years of work in deciding (for theoretically tractable problems!) how you select the state, find the right Hamiltonian, and actually calculate the time evolution operator (or if you prefer you can translate these words into your favorite way to formulate quantum mechanics; personally I like path integrals)... but in principle, there is no problem applying quantum mechanics to any system without strong gravity.

Second, if we *do* want to connect with a measurement, what do we calculate? This is highly situation dependent. Let's just focus on the "electron in the sun" example. While a particular electron at the center of the sun is surely not measurable (at least not by us), the state of the plasma (which includes the state of this electron) is quite relevant for the sun's dynamics. In turn, this affects observables like the temperature, magnetic field, rate of solar flares, etc. The observables will depend on the particular system and on what measurements we can do on that system. The problem is that theory does not tell us directly how these observables behave. However, once we know them, then the work begins to connect these observables to more fundamental, microscopic quantities, which  not themselves directly observable but which are simple enough that theory can give us a direct handle.